# Is it possible to choose a subsequence countable times in ZF?

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice

Rudin PMA p.157

I'm trying to prove;

"If $\{f_n\}$ is a pointwise bounded sequence of complex functions on a countable set $E$, then $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $\{f_{n_k}\}$ pointwise convergent on $E$"

It's clear that Rudin made dependent choice.

I'm trying to prove this withouc AC and want to know if there is a way to choose a subsequence of a sequence. That is when $\{n\}$ is a given sequence, then i want to choose a subsequence $\{n_k\}$, then again choose a subsequence of $\{n_{k_j}\}$ and again countable times.

Is it possible?

Or if one can prove this with a different argument, Or if it is unprovable, please let me know..

Thank you in advance

Comment: In other words: How much choice is needed for Tychonoff's theorem for a countable product of closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Nate Yes exactly

Comment: It seems to me the key is: given a bounded sequence $\{a_n\}$ (say in [0,1] for simplicity) can we *canonically* choose a convergent subsequence?  Here's a proposal: the set of subsequential limits of $\{a_n\}$ is closed and bounded, hence has a minimum element $a$.  (So we canonically chose a subsequential limit.)  Now choose the subsequence: let $n(k)$ be the least $n$ with $|a_n - a| < 1/k$.  Then $a_{n(k)} \to a$.

Comment: Oh wait: "the set of subsequential limits is closed": we have to be a little careful not to use choice in proving this.

Comment: @Nate Yeah, there exists a limit point $p$ which is a limit point of every $\{f_n(x_i)\}$ where $x_i$ enumerate $E$.

Comment: Even if you can select your subsequences countably many times without AC, there is no guarantee that their intersection will be non-empty.

Comment: @TonyK Aren't they compact?

Comment: You seem to think that if you can produce a nested sequence of subsequences, then this will answer the question. But the intersection (or limit, if you prefer) of a nested sequence of subsequences can be empty.

Comment: For instance: the first subsequence is $\{1,2,3,4,5,...\}$, the second subsequence is $\{2,3,4,5,6,...\}$, the third subsequence is $\{3,4,5,6,7,...\}$,...

Comment: @TonyK I didn't mean 'that' intersection, but i meant the intersection of "the set of limit points of $\{f_n(x_i)\}_{n\in\omega}$" where $x_i$ enumerate $E$. Sorry for the ambiguity of my words..

Comment: @Katlus: Whatever _you_ meant, do you agree with my objection to your suggested argument? If you choose a subsequence countably many times, you may end up with nothing.

Comment: @TonyK Oh. yes i agree.. i thought you were talking about my comments at the first.. now i see. I'm sorry

Comment: @TonyK: That is easily repaired, though: The $n$th time you choose a nested subsequence to restrict to, decide always to keep the first $n$ points in the previous sequence unchanged. This will not change the limit of the subsequence you restrict to, and the eventual nest of subsequences is guaranteed to have infinite intersection.

Comment: (Or, equivalently, once you have chosen your sequence $f_{ij}$ of nested subsequences, just consider $(f_{nn})_n$. That is eventually a subsequence of each of the original sequences).

Comment: It is (maybe) off the topic, but if $a_{n_k} \rightarrow p$ and $a_{n_j} \rightarrow p$, then $a_{n_k \cup n_j} \rightarrow p$?

Comment: To be sure I understand the question, there is a countable set $E$ and a sequence of complex functions whose domains are all $E$, and at each $e\in E$ we have that the no function in the sequence maps $e$ beyond some disc; **then** we can find a subsequence which converges pointwise.

Comment: @Asaf That's right

Comment: Something is strange here, what if all the $f_n$'s map into the unit disc but the union of the ranges is a discrete set. How could you construct a p.w.-convergent subsequence?

Comment: Proof for Arzela-Ascoli's theorem in wikipedia is exactly the same as Rudin's and wikipedia says nothing about AC and the argument can be done by Induction. Why?

Comment: Typo: 'wikipedia says' the argument can be done by induction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, here is a proof:

- Every bounded sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ has a limit point.

> Suppose not,let $K$ be a compact set containing the sequence, then $\{x_n\}$ must be infinite;no AC needed to prove this, thus for each $k\in{K}$ define $s(k)$ where $s(k)$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $(B_{1/n}(k)-\{k\})\cap{\{x_n\}}=\emptyset$, then $\{B_{\frac{1}{s(k)}}(k)\}_{k\in{K}}$ is an open covering of $K$ with no finite subcover, since $\{x_n\}$ is infinite.

- For every bounded sequence $\{x_n\}$ there exists a uniquely determined converging subsequence $\{f(\{x_n\})_m\}_{m\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ of $\{x_n\}$.

> Let $E$ be the set of limit points of $\{x_n\}$, then $E$ is a bounded set since our sequence is bounded, let $a=infE$; $a$ exixts since $E$ is nonempty by what it was shown above, then every neighborhood of $a$ intersects the sequence; this is easily seen without using AC, then for each $m>0$ let $k(0)=0$ and for each $n$ let $k(m+1))$ be the least positive integer $r$ greater than all of $k(0),\ldots,k(m)$ and such that $|a-x_r|<\frac{1}{m+1}$. Define $f(\{x_n\})_m=x_{k(m)}$ for all $m\in{\mathbb{N}}$, it is clear that the series $\{f(\{x_n\})_m\}_{m\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ converges to $a$.

Now using the notation on page 157 in Rudin’s PMA define $S_0=\{x_n\}$, and for $m\in{\mathbb{N}}, S_{m+1}=f(S_m)$

Answer (score 1):

Let's confine ourselves to Real-valued functions.

That is, let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of pointwise bounded functions on $E$ such that $f_n$ maps from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x_i$ enumerate $E$.

Let $S_1 = \{n_k \subset \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} : f_{n_k}(x_1) \rightarrow \limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_1) \}$

and $g_1:\omega \rightarrow \bigcup_{n_k \in S_1} rng(n_k)$ be the isomorphism.

$S_{i+1} = \{g_{i_{n_k}} \subset \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} : f_{g_{i_{n_k}}}(x_{i+1}) \rightarrow \limsup_{n\to\infty} f_{g_{i_n}}(x_{i+1}) \}$

and $g_{i+1}:\omega \rightarrow \bigcup_{g_{i_{n_k}}\in S_{i+1}} rng(g_{i_{n_k}})$ be the isomorphism.

(Note that $S_i$ is nonempty and well-defined since $f_n$ is pointwise bounded on $E$)

By induction, $\{g_i\}$ is well defined and $g_{i+1}$ is a subsequence of $g_i$.

Define $h(n)=g_n(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Then for any $i\in\mathbb{N}$, $f_{h(n)}(x_i)$ is convergent. Q.E.D.

This can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^k$.