# Totally bounded, sequentially compact, complete, bounded, closed, equicontinuous $\Rightarrow$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, axiom-of-choice

Related; [When $K$ is compact, if $S\subset C_b(K)$ is closed,bounded and equicontinuous, then $S$ is compact? (ZF)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265634/when-k-is-compact-if-s-subset-c-bk-is-closed-bounded-and-equicontinuous)

I just edited my whole question since i think it was a bit messy.

Here is my question.

Let $K$ be a separable compact metric space and $S\subset C(K,\mathbb{C})$.

Let $S$ be closed,bounded,uniformly equicontinuous on $K$, sequentially compact, totally bounded and complete.

Then is $S$ compact? (in ZF)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Of course, if you do not assume AC, you should say what "compact" means.  If it involves the word "finite" you should say what that means.

Comment: @GEdgar Isn't it common to denote finite as a set equipotent with a finite ordinal in ZF?

Comment: Just make it clear you don't mean Dedekind finite.  Every open cover has a Dedekind finite subcover ... I wonder what those spaces are.

Comment: @GEdgar: It is the common terminology that "finite" means "smaller than $\aleph_0$", so there is no actual confusion. As for your question, assuming the axiom of choice - those are the compact spaces! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read an answer to a slightly different question [over at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45928/does-arzela-ascoli-require-choice/45931#45931).

The short answer is: Arzelà–Ascoli does require (a weak form of) choice.

Comment: But if you assume $K$ to be separable, then Arzela Ascoli Theorem does not require choice. So i did assume that $K$ to be separable.

Comment: @Katlus: Are you sure? Baire Category Theorem is true for separable metric spaces, but I'm not sure about Arzela-Ascoli. For more details see Herrlich's book chapter 4.9 (in particular p.99 and onwards).

Comment: @Asaf Yes, I am sure that "If $K$ is separable compact metric space and $f_n\in C(K,\mathbb{K})$ and $\{f_n\}$ is bounded and equicontinuous on $K$, then $\{f_n\}$ contains a uniformly convergent subsequence" is true under ZF.

Comment: Camilo's argument seems fine just using upper-bound-property of $\mathbb{R}$http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259319/is-it-possible-to-choose-a-subsequence-countable-times-in-zf